# Partitional vs. hierarchical clustering with distance matrix

Tags: r, machine-learning, clustering

I am exploring the flexibility of partitional clustering algorithms. In particular, I would like to introduce more general distances than the ones which are used by default.

Let us consider, for simplicity, `dbscan` contained in the R-package `fpc`. It allows the user to specify a "data matrix, data.frame, dissimilarity matrix or dist-object".

My idea would be to compute the distance matrix of the given data w.r.t. my chosen distance, and run `dbscan`.

Here comes the point where I am stuck. Is it true that specifying a distance matrix should lead inevitably to a hierarchical clustering? My intuition says that a hierarchical clustering in presence of  a distance matrix makes more sense that a partitional one on the elements of the matrix itself. As I am no expert in clustering, I cannot judge the above statement properly.

Would you use a partitional algorithm on the distance matrix of a given dataset? Is this correct?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to read up on Generalized DBSCAN. DBSCAN itself only needs a *binary* decision.

So in fact, you can map the matrix to a binary matrix $x\ge\varepsilon$ and then set $\varepsilon=.5$ and you will get the exact same result with DBSCAN. It only needs a predicate of "is a neighbor", not an actual measure of neighborness.

There exist improved versions of DBSCAN for a long time, namely [OPTICS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPTICS_algorithm), and just this year DBSCAN was revisited, incorporating ideas from OPTICS, as HDBSCAN*. Both of these actually produce a hierarchy.

Putting restrictions on the distance functions is mostly of interest for *performance*. Some distances can be accelerated with index structures, at which point these algorithm can run in *less* than $\mathcal O(n^2)$. Anything that is based on a distance matrix will obviously need at least $\mathcal O(n^2)$ memory and runtime.

The R options for clustering are in my opinion not very good. `fpc` is really slow. For clustering, I perfer [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/). It is very flexible; if you are interested in evaluating the flexibility of clustering algorithms you should probably have a good look at it. It also has support for index structures.

Comment: -thanks for your answer (as usual!). I do appreciate A LOT the time you spend to help me  :-) . I have seen ELKI few days ago...it looks cool. OPTICS seems quite good as well! Unfortunately there are still some missing pieces in my mind. For example: if I produce a (symmetric) distance matrix from my data, let us say with entries $(0,1,2,\sqrt{5}):=x$, then what does `dbscan` do? Does it begin to cluster the vector $x$ using the `eps` threshold? If yes...then I am confused: I used an ad hoc distance to get $x$ and `dbscan` uses its default one on it...

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. If `dbscan` is given a precomputed matrix, it will not need to re-compute any distance.

Comment: If dbscan is given the precomputed distance matrix, then it will begin to cluster the components of $x$ (as above), am I right? If yes, it will begin to check if there exist components of $x$ whose distance is <= eps from an initially selected component. To do so, dbscan must know what does it mean "distance <=eps". This is my issue: I used an ad hoc distance to produce the distance matrix, but after its computation dbscan checks the "eps" condition using a default one.  I am sorry if this makes no sense! It would be great you I could find the flaw(s) in what is above

Comment: It will not cluster the distance matrix. It will cluster the column indexes. Objects $i$ and $j$ are connected iff $x_{ij}\leq\varepsilon$. That's how distance matrixes work...

Comment: I see: so in presence of a distance matrix, no "<=eps" condition is checked AT ALL by dbscan. Unfortunately, one has to compute the entries of it :) Now it is clear, thanks @Anony-Mousse!

Comment: Sure it checked. The values $x_{ij}$ in the matrix are checked against the $\varepsilon$ threshold. It is a *distance matrix*. It stores the distance values to be checked.

Comment: I expressed myself in a sloppy way: I meant that no check with euclidean distance is performed. The check you are referring to makes full sense.