# Clustering given pairwise distances with unknown cluster number?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

I have a set of objects ${O_1, O_2, O_3, ..., O_n}$. I have calculated the pairwise distances of all possible pairs. The distances are stored in a $n\times n$ matrix $M$, with $M_{ij}$ being the distance between $O_i$ and $O_j$. Then it is natural to see $M$ is a symmetric matrix.

Now I wish to perform unsupervised clustering to these objects. After some searching, I find [Spectral Clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_clustering) may be a good candidate, since it deals with such pairwise-distance cases.

However, after carefully reading its description, I find it unsuitable in my case, as **it requires the number of clusters as the input**. Before clustering, I don't know the number of clusters. It has to be figured out by the algorithm while performing the clustering, like DBSCAN.

**Considering these, please suggest me some clustering methods that fit my case**, where

1. The pairwise distances are all available.
2. The number of clusters is unknown.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but can't you use DBSCAN or OPTICS? See also http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67686/partitional-vs-hierarchical-clustering-with-distance-matrix/ of which I think this question would count as a possible duplicate.

Comment: [Affinity Propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinity_propagation) ([Frey, 2007](http://genes.toronto.edu/index.php?q=affinity%20propagation)) fits the bill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many possible clustering methods, and none of them can be considered "best", everything depends on the data, as always:

- If you would like to use spectral clustering, but do not know the number of clusters before hand I suggest taking a look at the [self-tuning spectral clustering](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/lihi/Demos/SelfTuningClustering.html) or some [methods of determining the number of clusters](http://eprints.pascal-network.org/archive/00001544/01/clusterNumber.pdf)
- If you consider other algorithms you could try:

  - [DBScan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN)
  - [Optics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPTICS_algorithm)
  - [Density-Link-Clustering](http://www.dbs.informatik.uni-muenchen.de/~achtert/papers/PAKDD06_deliClu.pdf)
  - [Hierarchical clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as I said, **given my case where I have already the pairwise distances and don't know the number of the clusters**, what method may be suggested? So the methods that you suggest all deal with the pairwise distance? You didn;t mention the fitness to my case here. COuld you please kindly confirm? THanks!

Comment: DBScan, Optics and HC can be used with custom distances, and all of them do not require number of clusers, density link is a hybrid of these approaches so shares their characteristic. Spectral clustering was your choice, I only provided you with the modifications that deal with the number of clusters.